# Keeping the font size between pdfLaTex and XeLaTex

Tags: xetex, pdftex, fontsize, japanese

I'm currently compiling my document in pdfLaTex, but I have one of my references that is in Japanese and nothing is displayed. The only solution I found is to use XeLaTeX with these commands:

```latex
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{IPAMincho}
\setCJKsansfont{IPAGothic}
\setCJKmonofont{IPAGothic}
```

But when I change the compiler from pdfLaTex to XeLaTex on Overleaf (without changing anything in my code), the text is taking more space. The 10pt font is looking bigger, why?

If there is a way to not change the font size OR to use Japanese characters in ref with pdfLatex, I'd be interested!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like XeLaTex changes more than just the font size.

Comment: Wnat's the default font size used by xeCJK? Does anything change if you provide `10pt` as one of the document class options?

Comment: if you have only one reference it should be quite possible to insert some japanese there, e.g. simply with a small image.